# How much worldbuilding of Sodor was included in the original Rev. W. Awdry stories?

Tags: setting, fictional-languages, rev-w-awdry, the-railway-series

The famous [Railway Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Railway_Series) by the Rev. W. Awdry is set in the fictional island of [Sodor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodor_(fictional_island)), situated between northern England and the Isle of Man. Today, reading about Sodor on Wikipedia, I was surprised to learn the amount of worldbuilding that went into it, including a flag, coat of arms, and even a fictional language called [Sudric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodor_(fictional_island)#Language).

As a child, I devoured all of Rev. W. Awdry's Railway Series stories, but I don't remember any references to a Sudric language spoken by the people of Sodor. Those days might, however, have predated my Tolkienian appreciation for worldbuilding and fictional languages, so it's possible that it was mentioned and I missed it. How much of the worldbuilding of Sodor actually made it into Awdry's original stories, and how much was only published in [*The Island of Sodor: Its People, History and Railways*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_in_The_Railway_Series#The_Island_of_Sodor:_Its_People,_History_and_Railways) or in the later continuations by Christopher Awdry and other writers? I know there was a map of Sodor included somewhere, with its connections to mainland Britain, but was the language ever mentioned?